# Can more than one vortex form around a bathtub drain and what determines position?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I don't think I have ever seen more than one "vortex" or whatever you call the tornado-like helical thing that forms when water is draining from a tub. Is the position a function of the shape of the tub or the amount of water or is it random?

Comment: If the drain is growing in volume and depth , the number of vortex's are determined by the rate and magnitude the drain is expanding. And eventually they will all form back to one once they exceed all the volume  they occupy.

Answer (score 1):

The vortices are formed near the hole. There may be multiple suvh vortices, but they soon coalesce into one vortex due to perturbations.